# Get substring from varchar column in SQL server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have one column called Name and in the column I have values

```
Name
001 BASI Distributor (EXAM)
002 BASI Supplier (EXAM2)
MASI DISTRIBUTOR (EXAM002)
MASI SUPPLIER (EXAM003)
EXAM_ND Distributor Success System Test (EXAM_ND)
EXAM_SS Supplier Success System Test (EXAM_SS)
```

now I want to separate the value inside the `()` from this whole string.How I will get this I tried for the `SUBSTRING (Name ,22 ,4 )` but this will help for single one I want to get the result using some unique solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (st NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @temp (st)
VALUES 
     ('001 BASI Distributor (EXAM)'),
     ('002 BASI Supplier (EXAM2)'),
     ('MASI DISTRIBUTOR (EXAM002)'),
     ('MASI SUPPLIER (EXAM003)'),
     ('EXAM_ND Distributor Success System Test (EXAM_ND)'),
     ('EXAM_SS Supplier Success System Test (EXAM_SS)')

SELECT SUBSTRING(
     st, 
     CHARINDEX('(', st) + 1, 
     CHARINDEX(')', st) - CHARINDEX('(', st) - 1
)
FROM @temp
```

Output -

```
-------------
EXAM
EXAM2
EXAM002
EXAM003
EXAM_ND
EXAM_SS
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(Name,
        CHARINDEX('(', Name) + 1,
        CHARINDEX(')', Name) - CHARINDEX('(', Name) - 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

One more option:

```
SELECT *, REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Name, CHARINDEX('(', Name) + 1, LEN(Name)), ')', '')
FROM dbo.test136
```

This spares one `CHARINDEX` call (searching for the closing `)`) on the assumption that your `Name` values never contain anything after the parenthesised part. If they do, use other suggestions.

Comment: Thanks comrade. Sadly that didn't have enough time to up-vote @techdo answer.

Answer (score -1):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Name, PATINDEX('%(%', Name)+1, LEN(Name)), ')', '')
FROM 
    YourTable
```